# raphaeljs drag and drop

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am using rapaeljs for my web app.
I want to set dropable boundries of the object. Object can move in dropable area. Once an object come in dropable area, there should be no way out for the object.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Raphael has built in drag and drop support through **[`.drag()`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html)**. Use it in the form `element.drag(start, move, up);` Where the 3 arguments are 3 function references to the functions you write that deal with the mousedown, movement, and mouseup events respectively.

Note how `this.ox` and `this.oy` is used to store the starting positions and `dx` and `dy` is used for the movement.

**[The following](http://jsfiddle.net/nCBwC/)** implements a drag and drop on a box. The box can always be moved, but once it's in the "jail" box, it cannot be moved back out. When the box crosses into the jail, the color is instantly changed, to signal the user that the functionality has changed.

This is implemented with a **[`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)** and **[`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)** adjustment of the box's position after `dx` and `dy` are added to the current position:

```
var nowX, nowY, move = function (dx, dy) {
    // move will be called with dx and dy
    if (this.attr("y") > 60 || this.attr("x") > 60)
        this.attr({x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy + dy}); 
    else {
        nowX = Math.min(60, this.ox + dx);
        nowY = Math.min(60, this.oy + dy);
        nowX = Math.max(0, nowX);
        nowY = Math.max(0, nowY);            
        this.attr({x: nowX, y: nowY });
        if (this.attr("fill") != "#000") this.attr({fill: "#000"}); 
    }
}
```

You could also make it so that the box cannot be picked up again once it is put down in the "jail" box. This could be done with a test of position in the `move()` or `start()` function or the use of `c.undrag(f)` in the `stop()` function.

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nCBwC/)**

```
window.onload = function() {
var nowX, nowY, R = Raphael("canvas", 500, 500),
    c = R.rect(200, 200, 40, 40).attr({
            fill: "hsb(.8, 1, 1)",
            stroke: "none",
            opacity: .5,
            cursor: "move"
        }),
    j = R.rect(0,0,100,100),
    // start, move, and up are the drag functions
    start = function () {
        // storing original coordinates
        this.ox = this.attr("x");
        this.oy = this.attr("y");
        this.attr({opacity: 1});
        if (this.attr("y") < 60 &&  this.attr("x") < 60)
            this.attr({fill: "#000"});        
    },
    move = function (dx, dy) {
        // move will be called with dx and dy
        if (this.attr("y") > 60 || this.attr("x") > 60)
            this.attr({x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy + dy}); 
        else {
            nowX = Math.min(60, this.ox + dx);
            nowY = Math.min(60, this.oy + dy);
            nowX = Math.max(0, nowX);
            nowY = Math.max(0, nowY);            
            this.attr({x: nowX, y: nowY });
            if (this.attr("fill") != "#000") this.attr({fill: "#000"}); 
        }
    },
    up = function () {
        // restoring state
        this.attr({opacity: .5});
        if (this.attr("y") < 60 && this.attr("x") < 60)
            this.attr({fill: "#AEAEAE"});            
    };   
    // rstart and rmove are the resize functions;
    c.drag(move, start, up);
};​
```

Comment: If I try to change the element to anything other than a rectangle, e.g., a circle (using R.circle(200, 200, 40)...) or an ellipse, I can no longer move it. Does anyone else have the same issue? Seems unlikely that the drag() method should be specific for rectangles.