# Raphael.js: How to move element only inside a path?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have this `path` and `rectangle`:

```
poly = 'M118,129 L393,130 L311,263 L512,271 L438,122 L745,139 L650,293 L787,263 L765,511 L636,370 L641,529 L319,561 L545,353 L269,366 L355,452 L117,537 L20,332 L246,278 L293,171 L143,282Z';
p = paper.path(poly);
rect = paper.rect(135,135,20,20);
```

I checked out this [raphaeljs drag and drop question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675519/raphaeljs-drag-and-drop), but this works only in rectangle-in-rectangle case.

Is there any way to move a rect only inside of a path? It is possible?

Comment: Since you can specify a function for each event (eg. *start*, *drag* and *end*), why don't you limit the movements of your draggable element by hand ? You can have the position of the dragging point, and you already have the coordinates of your path.

Comment: I want to do something like the default Raphael.js movement in quarantine. For ex: you can't move the object out of the quarantine object. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is, this what I am talking about in my first comment. You first need to implement events to drag elements by mouse. Once you did that, you are only missing the narrowing part. And it's all about maths I guess. The hard part in your question is knowing whether the element is inside the path or not.