# How to drag a svg element

Tags: svg, raphael

I have created an arrow using SVG

```
var arrow = gaugeSvg
    .path('M 0 0 L 40 -34 L 40 -14 L 80 -14 L 80 14 L 40 14 L 40 34 Z')
    .attr({'stroke': 'black', 'fill': 'black', 'enable': 'true'})
    .translate(left + width, goalY);
```

Now I want to drag this arrow vertically. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use Element.drag(). See Raphael documentation here http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.drag

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I have one query:
Element.drag(onmove, onstart, onend, [mcontext], [scontext], [econtext])
in this fuction what should give as arguments ?

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675519/raphaeljs-drag-and-drop, there'a a full explanation on how it works, how to implement it and a jsfiddle is provided too. Cheers